# PHP Reconstruct Array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to reconstruct an array. Here is the original array:

```
array(8) {
      [0] => array(1)
      {
            ["L_TRANSACTIONID0"] => string(17) "62M97388AY676841D"
      }

      [1] => array(1)
      {
            ["L_TRANSACTIONID1"] => string(17) "9FF44950UY3240528"
      }

      [2] => array(1)
      {
            ["L_STATUS0"] => string(9) "Completed"
      }

      [3] => array(1)
      {
            ["L_STATUS1"] => string(9) "Completed"
      }
}
```

I would like to reconstruct it to be as such:

```
array(2) {
      [0] => array(2)
      {
            ["L_TRANSACTIONID0"] => string(17) "62M97388AY676841D"
            ["L_STATUS0"] => string(9) "Completed"
      }
      [1] => array(1)
      {
            ["L_TRANSACTIONID1"] => string(17) "9FF44950UY3240528"
            ["L_STATUS1"] => string(9) "Completed"
      }
}
```

Notice that the KEYS both match with the numeric representation... Is this at all possible?

edit:

here is my code I am using:

```
        foreach($comparison as $key => $val) {
        $findme1 = 'L_TRANSACTID'.$i++;
        $findme2 = 'L_STATUS'.$c++;
        $arrDisable = array($findme1,$findme2);
        if( in_array($key, $arrDisable ) ) {
          unset( $comparison[ $key ][$val]);
        }
            if( in_array($key, $arrDisable) ) {
        unset( $comparison[ $key ][$val]);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Yes. But you will need to write your own code to do this. That is to say, there is no single, magic PHP function.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What have you tried so far? We're not here to do your job for you, so show what you've attempted.

Comment: added code I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$labels = array('L_TRANSACTIONID', 'L_STATUS');
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $key = str_replace($labels, '', key($val));
  $res[$key] = isset($res[$key]) ? array_merge($res[$key], $val) : $val;
}
print_r($res);
```

http://codepad.org/MwqTPqtA

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the the vector cointains pairs L_TRANSACTIONIDn / L_STATUSn keys,that is to say, for each transactionID, there is a corresponding status, what you can do, is to get the number of id/status records (which should equal the length of the initial array, divided by two), and compose the resultin keys, by increasing the current element count.

Could look something like this:

```
$numItems = sizeof($myInitialArray) / 2;
$newArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++)
{
    $itemID = $i * 2; // since we're getting id/status pairs, we're using a step equal to 2

    $newArray[] = array(
        ("L_TRANSACTIONID" . $i) => $myInitialArray[$itemID], // this is the id value
        ("L_STATUS" . $i) => $myInitialArray[$itemID + 1] // this is the status for that id
    );
}
```

Hope this helps. Have a great day!